# Tooltipster change title using jQuery

Tags: jquery, tooltipster

Okay I implemented Tooltipster successfully and I have created an image with the following title:

```
<img id="DeviceIvan" class="tooltipsterIvan" src="Slike/urSamsungS7.png"
title="Some Tekst bla bla works great."/>
```

Now I have need the title text to change when I select a different option. I usually do this:

```
$('#DeviceIvan').html("I have changed the text yo!!!");
```

But this does not appear to work.

I also tried:

```
var image = document.querySelector('img');
image.title = 'Your title'; // Assigning directly to attribute.
image.setAttribute('title', 'Your other title'); // Assigning by method.
```

But that also did not work.
**Can someone help with changing the title using jQuery ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is quite "minimal"...
Since I can't see how you implemented [Tooltipster](http://iamceege.github.io/tooltipster/), I've done it real simple in this [**codePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/GmEXMr?editors=1010)

Now, once you instantiated Tooltipster, to change the title you have to `destroy` the first instance, change the title...
And then, re-instantiate Tooltipster.

I placed a button in the example to do so.

```
// On load instantiation of Tooltipster.
$('#DeviceIvan').tooltipster({
  theme: 'tooltipster-punk'
});

$("#test").on("click",function(){

  // Destroy the first instance.
  $('#DeviceIvan').tooltipster("destroy");

  // change the title attribute and re-instantiate.
  $('#DeviceIvan').attr("title","I have changed the text yo!!!").tooltipster({
    theme: 'tooltipster-punk'
  });
});
```

Comment: Yes, this worked ! Thank you very much @Louis Patrice Bessette